# UITableViewCell ImageView too large on iPhone X

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, iphone-x

I am using a Storyboard and setting a `UIImageView` for my `UITableViewCell`. I have a @2x and @3x version of the image, at 50x50 and 100x100.

This looks how I want it to on an iPhone 6, 7, 8:

[image]

iPhone X:

[image]

As you can see the icon is much larger on the iPhone X. (I realize the screen is larger on the X, but the icons are obviously much larger).

**Any ideas on how to fix this?**

Comment: Shouldn't your `@3x` image assets have a 1.5x larger width than your `@2x` assets, not 2x larger? So your `@3x` assets should be 75x75?

Comment: Yeah, that would be why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the size of your image assets.

> I have a @2x and @3x version of the image, at 50x50 and 100x100.

But `@3x` assets should have a width and height that is 1.5x larger than their `@2x` counterparts, not 2x larger. So if your 50x50 `@2x` assets are appearing correctly, your `@3x` assets should be 75x75, not 100x100.

Comment: You were indeed right. Now sure how I missed something so simple. :(